# Adding multiple logos in beamer template

Tags: beamer, figure-placement

Suppose I have a beamer template and I want two logos to appear, one in the top left and the other in the top right. I am using `\pgfdeclareimage` in a sty file to declare images:

```
footlinecolor{} % Default: no footline
\pgfdeclareimage[width=0.13\paperwidth]{blacklogo}{images/lille.png}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=0.13\paperwidth]{redlogo}{images/circular_rgb.png}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=0.09\paperwidth]{whitelogo}{images/circular_white.png}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=0.09\paperwidth]{nologo}{images/placeholder.png}
\newcommand{\@UIClogo}{redlogo}
\newcommand{\@UIClogob}{blacklogo}
```

Then, I put the logos in the right positions:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vspace{0.03\textwidth}\hspace{0.04\textwidth}\pgfuseimage{\@UIClogo}}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vspace{0.03\textwidth}\hspace{0.85\textwidth}\pgfuseimage{\@UIClogob}}
```

However, the first logo doesn't show up in my slides, and only the second one (top right) appears, as shown in the picture:
[image: Only black logo appears]

WHich shows that only `blacklogo` appears, however `redlogo` which supposed to appear on the left side does not show up. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your given code snippets be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Thank you for your message. I edited my text, hopefully the problem is clear now.

Comment: @Ayoubayjx Please always include a small, but compilable test file in your questions. Having to first puzzle your code fragments together before even starting to work on an answer is rather boring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{...}` will replace all the previous content with `...`. So in your second call, you replace the first picture with the second one.

If you would like two images, add them at the same time:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareimage[width=0.13\paperwidth]{blacklogo}{example-image-duck}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=0.13\paperwidth]{redlogo}{example-image}

\newcommand{\@UIClogo}{redlogo}
\newcommand{\@UIClogob}{blacklogo}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vspace{0.03\textwidth}\hspace{0.04\textwidth}\pgfuseimage{\@UIClogo}\hfill\pgfuseimage{\@UIClogob}\hspace{0.04\textwidth}\mbox{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could use `\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{<before>}{<after>}` to add things to an existing template without overwriting it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareimage[width=0.13\paperwidth]{blacklogo}{example-image-duck}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=0.13\paperwidth]{redlogo}{example-image}

\newcommand{\@UIClogo}{redlogo}
\newcommand{\@UIClogob}{blacklogo}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vspace{0.03\textwidth}\hspace{0.04\textwidth}\pgfuseimage{\@UIClogo}}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\hfill\pgfuseimage{\@UIClogob}\hspace{0.04\textwidth}\mbox{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Comment: @Ayoubayjx You're welcome!